# How to share config files between webjobs in azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I currently have 7 webjobs that all connect to the same database with the same credentials. I want to have one file that all of the webjobs include so I don't have to make changes about username/password/host 7 times.

I've tried having the file be in the parent directory to all of the webjobs, but it appears that when a webjob is triggerd it's put in to a sandbox in a different directory.

This is the path my program prints out when running `D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered`, but this is the directory that I put my webjobs in via ftp `/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/triggered`

Is there a way that I can load the same file in all of my webjobs without having 7 instances of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to set an App Setting (or Connection String) in the Azure Portal (or equivalently via the Azure ARM API). When you do that, the setting will be available to all your WebJobs.

Comment: Is there a more complex solution if I wanted to do the same thing with a file that has functions that all of my webjobs use? Also your "hooking up a scheduler job to a web job" blog post was insanely useful!

Comment: Is your Job .net or something else?

Comment: As for the scheduler, glad the blog helped! Though note that we now try to move people to use the cron support instead of scheduler. See [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON). Anyway, different topic :)

Comment: The job is python. And I ended up not doing the cron because that requires always on

Comment: Fair about cron. I'm no Python expert, but is it possible to import a file that's in a different folder?

Comment: Absolutely, but it looks like the directory changes once the webjobs is triggered. This is the path my program prints out when running "D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered", but this is the directory that I put my webjobs in via ftp "/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/triggered".

Comment: You can avoid the different folder using a `settings.job`. See [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#webjob-working-directory) for details. You won't lose anything since the copying is mostly useful for .net where things can get locked when loaded.